# Replace cells of a table based on a vector (except for blank cells and without a dictionary)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a table like this (the first row is header):

```
ID Sire Dam
EL SF NA
GN SF UJ
SF SF NA
```

and a vector like this:

```
G<-c("10325", "6788" ,"1140","6788","6789" , "14140", "6788" )
```

I wonder how can I replace cells of the table based on that vector (except for blank cells) to get this table (without a dictionary):

```
ID Sire Dam
10325 6788 NA
1140 6788 6789
14140 6788 NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do this -

```
tmp <- t(df)
df[] <- t(replace(tmp, !is.na(tmp), G))
df

#     ID Sire  Dam
#1 10325 6788 <NA>
#2  1140 6788 6789
#3 14140 6788 <NA>
```

Replacement works columnwise but you are changing the values rowwise hence transpose is necessary.